# c# Template specialization

Tags: c#, generics

can i :

```
    class X<T>
        where T : EventArgs
    {

    }

    class X<T>
        where T:Exception
    {

    }
```

in C#?

Comment: It isn't too clear what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: -1 - in case you did not read the documentatioon, C# does not have TEMPLATES, it has GENERICS. There is a distinct difference - which makes specialization impossible.

Comment: Good point, he's probably wanting to do templating as in C++. Glad it's not supported though, makes things a pain.

Comment: iv'e read the docs dont worry.
still i want specialization, saw it in C++ and liked it... I could derive from a common interface, and achive something really close, actually....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same class name for the generic constraints.

You can use base classes as constraints, but the constraint then means that you can only use derived classes - in your examples, only classes that derive from `EventArgs` in the first example and classes that derive from `Excpetion` in the second.

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) for constraints on type parameters.

Comment: exactly what i want, one class for T's that derive from one class and anothore for those deriving from another

Answer (score 0):

No, because the two clases do have the same name.

What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean 2 classes with the **same name** in the same namespace with different generic type parameters - then **NO**, you can't!

You can only have one class in the **where** clause. You could use the

> System.Runtime.InteropServices._Exception

interface to accept Exceptions (that would be an ugly hack, though).

If you put them in separate namespaces, you can.